# Создать регулярное выражение posix: любые года, кроме двух лет

Tags: регулярные-выражения, posix

Нужно создать регулярное выражение в posix, которое будет находить любые года в скобках, кроме 2021 и 2022 года. Пока получилось только такое:
`/\([0-9][0-9][^2][^1-2]\)`
Нужно чтобы находило 1,3,5 строки. А это выражение не находит 1.

```
(2020)
(2021)
(1999)
(2022)
(2030)
```

Comment: Тоже работает \(\d\d(?!21|22)\d\d\)

Comment: Писал выражение для newsboat, который использует выражения "like-posix" в своих фильтрах. Так вот работают также !~ \"\(202[1,2]\)\" или !~ \"2021|2022\" Проблема была в !~

Answer (score 1):

Выражение, совместимое со стандартом POSIX ERE:

```
\([0-9]{2}([01][0-9]|20|2[3-9]|[3-9][0-9])\)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/piwV73/2).

*Подробности*:

- `\(` - `(`
- `[0-9]{2}` - две цифры
- `([01][0-9]|20|2[3-9]|[3-9][0-9])`:

  - `[01][0-9]|` - от 00 до 19 или
  - `20|` - 20 или
  - `2[3-9]|` - от 23 до 29
  - `[3-9][0-9]` - от 30 до 99
- `\)` - `)`

Для преобразования выражения в POSIX BRE (расширенный в утилитах GNU) измените экранирование:

```
([0-9]\{2\}\([01][0-9]\|20\|2[3-9]\|[3-9][0-9]\))
```